# Custom exception class not being compiled into .class file

Tags: java, eclipse, class, exception, jar

I have created a pretty simple custom class that extends Exception, code listed below.  The problem I'm running into is that this specific class is not being compiled into a .class file (within the *build/classes* directory, and the jar file for the project).  All other classes are compiled into .class files and packaged into a .jar file as expected.

jUnit tests run fine, even when they are run from other projects in the workspace, but when I attempt to reference this project from another project that depends on a jar the code is failing with a NoClassDefFoundError exception because it can't find this class in the .jar file that's generated.

I'm using Eclipse and Maven.  All other classes in the same project appear to be compiling just fine and Google and Stack Overflow have not yielded any clues.

The class code is as follows:

```
public class DownstreamSystemFailureException extends Exception {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5124591997847109725L;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private String systemDescription = null;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Exception innerException = null;

public DownstreamSystemFailureException( String systemDescription, Exception innerException )
{
    this.systemDescription = systemDescription;
    this.innerException = innerException;
}

}
```

Comment: is the .java file for the exception not in the src tree?  Is it in a weird place?  or is your build that creates the jar excluding it via a pattern?

Comment: Seems fine, but I would call super(innerException); instead of saving it separately.  With eclipse, sometimes you need to run 'clean' on the project to make it pick up .java files it missed.

Comment: No, it is sitting right next to other files which are being compiled just fine.  The build isn't excluding anything, but just to make sure I completely renamed it to "Foo" and am still getting the same result.  Good idea, though, thanks.

Comment: if you run mvn install from the command line, and inspect the jar file, is the class file in there? And does that other project refer to your Eclipse project or the install'ed jar in the local repo?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your jar with a different tool...

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have declared a `package` at the top of your custom Exception.  Using the default package for classes is not recommended, and you will have trouble finding them within a jar.